# Can hadoop streaming and oozie read input from a TCP socket?

Tags: sockets, tcp, hadoop-streaming, oozie, hue

I am trying to use the Oozie web portal to run a hadoop streaming job. Is it possible for the input to the job to come from a TCP socket?

Answer (score 0):

The input of the job can be read by your streaming program. Just it might not be parallelizable much if there is only one socket.